# Uninstall the application without user interaction through package manager?

Tags: android, package, uninstallation, android-package-managers

I'm a new Android developer and trying to make a package manager app. I have listed all installed apps, and now I want to uninstall the particular app without user interaction. Is it possible with unrooted phones?

Comment: why don't you use an existing manager?

Comment: which type of existing manager? @DiligentKeyPresser, can you please be specific.

Comment: It's not possible

Answer (score 0):

The PackageManager class contains a [@hide method : `deletePackage`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f76a50c/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#2236). BUT you can't use it because :

1. It's an hidden method, therefore the only way to call it in a normal App is to use reflection (it is not recommended because it may break in future version of the Android API)
2. Usage of this method requires the permission `android.Manifest.permission#DELETE_PACKAGES` and this permission can only be granted to apps signed with the system key. (i.e. even if you ask this permission in your manifest it won't be granted unless your app is signed with the system key)

So you can't do it in a simple/standard app. Your only solution (on a non-rooted phone) is to sign your app with the system key and to do so you need to negotiate with the manufacturer so that your app get signed with their system key.